# Convert txt file with multiple columns to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.6, csv

I have a .txt file in the following format:

```
AM|75019|Caribbean from 15N to 18N between 80W and 85W|18.757950|-81.741300
AM|75021|Caribbean from 15N to 18N between 72W and 80W|18.757950|-81.741300
AM|75015|Caribbean approaches to the Windward Passage|15.133340|-68.139050
```

I want to extract only the first two columns to use as `key:value`. For example, `AM:75019`, `AM:75021`, etc. I'm new to python (using 2.6) and am not sure how to do this. I've searched and found multiple answers that don't entirely make sense since there are multiple columns.

Comment: Here is the pseudo algorithm to not breast feed you the answer: you need to find a character which delimits your columns, then for each line, split this line using this delimiter. Then you get a list of strings, which you can work with to create your dictionary.

Comment: Use regular expression!

Comment: Side note, if you're new to Python, if possible, upgrade from 2.6 to something more widespread. 3.x is usually fine, but even 2.7 is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python cannot have duplicate keys, so the closest thing you could do would be to store a list of values associated with each key.

Your file is composed of character separated values, so using Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html#module-csv) module would make parsing the file into separate fields trivial.

Here's one way to accomplish what you want. Note that you could also use the [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) class, which was added to Python v2.5, instead of defining one of your own as shown below:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

class ListDict(dict):
    """ Dictionary who's values are lists. """
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = self[key] = []
        return value

filename = 'multi_col.csv'

lstdct = ListDict()
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|'):
        key, value = row[:2]
        lstdct[key].append(value)

pprint(lstdct)  # -> {'AM': ['75019', '75021', '75015']}
```

Comment: This does work, but how do I then access one of the key values? I tried lstdct.get("75013") but get a return value of None.

Comment: The values for each key are stored in its associated list, so `lstdct.get('AM')` (or `lstdct['AM']`) is the list of them. Individual items within those can be accessed by specifying an integer index. e.g. `lstdct['AM'][0]`,  `lstdct['AM'][1]`, etc. You could also loop through them all with something like `for flight in lstdct.get('AM', []): ...`. You can also easily check to see if a key is in the dictionary (and avoid creating an unneeded empty list) by using a conditional like `if 'AM' in lstdct: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps and get the expected response as output array

Add file.txt to the project structure
 - Add below code in the new extractinfo.py
 - Execute it

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
content = f.read()
allLines = content.split('\n')
output = []
for singleLine in allLines:
    singleLine = singleLine.split('|')
    extractedJSON = {}
    extractedJSON[singleLine[0]] = singleLine[1]
    output.append(extractedJSON)
print "output"
print output
f.close()
```

I have attached the image of running code.[image: Image Showing running code]

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the [split function](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Using the '|' separator you will obtain for every line several tokens. For your purpose you only need to use the first two.

Here is a small snippet

```
ze_dict = {}
ze_file = open(my_file_path, 'r')
ze_lines = ze_file.read().splitlines()
for l in ze_lines:
    ze_tokens = l.split('|')
    ze_dict[ze_tokens[0]] = ze_tokens[1]
ze_file.close()
```

Ofc you may add error control in this snippet !

Please note this is note the most pythonic way to do this (see other answers)

Answer (score 0):

**Following code will make what you want:**

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = {line.split('|')[0]: line.split('|')[1] for line in f}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract only the first to columns to use as key:value. For
>   example, AM:75019, AM:75021, etc.....

**If a key is duplicated in dict the second key-value pair will overwrite the first as a dictionary can only have one value per key.**

If want values with same keys you can have look at [***defaultdict***](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)

Here is sample code,

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict

In [2]: lines = tuple(open('test.txt', 'r'))

In [3]: data_dict = defaultdict(list)

In [4]: for line in lines:
   ...:     data_dict[line.split('|')[0]].append(line.split('|')[1])
   ...:

In [5]: data_dict
Out[5]: defaultdict(list, {'AM': ['75019', '75021', '75015']})

In [6]:
```